# How to use MTCNN for 68 point facial training？

Tags: pytorch, face-detection

I am using MTCNN for incremental training, increasing the number of key points from 5 to 68, using ibug as the data source_ 300W_ Large_ Face_ Landmark_ Dataset. I have encountered the following issues

1. Loss cannot converge, hovering around 0.06

I tried using resnet18 instead of ONet network, but the accuracy of boxes output decreased and the landmark effect slightly improved.Enter a picture size of 96*96

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models


class ResNetFeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResNetFeatureExtractor, self).__init__()
        resnet = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)  # 使用预训练的ResNet-18
        resnet.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False)
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[:-2])  # 去掉最后两层（全局平均池化和全连接层）

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.features(x)


class FaceDetectionNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FaceDetectionNet, self).__init__()
        self.feature_extractor = ResNetFeatureExtractor()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256 * 4 * 4, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 4)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(256, 68 * 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        features = self.feature_extractor(x)
        x = self.conv(features)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        confidence = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
        bb_offset = self.fc3(x)
        landmark_offset = self.fc4(x)
        return confidence, bb_offset, landmark_offset
```

I hope to receive some optimization suggestions